# Java EE Web Security with WildFly 8

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, hash, wildfly-8

I am trying to implement a security on a simple web application but I have not been able to get it right.

I have the DataSource "SecurityTestDS" working.
In standalone.xml I have:

```
<default-security-domain value="jdbc-security-domain"/>
<security-domain name="jdbc-security-domain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
        <!--<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">-->
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/SecurityTestDS"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from cb_users where username = ?"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select groupname Roles from cb_groups where username = ?"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>                        
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

jboss-web.xml contains

```
<security-domain>jdbc-security-domain</security-domain>
<!--    <security-domain>java:/jaas/jdbc-security-domain</security-domain>-->
<disable-audit>false</disable-audit>
```

web.xml contains:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>protected-pages</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>protected-pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbc-security-domain</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

login.jsp

```
<form action="j_security_check" method=post>
    <p>
        <strong>Username:</strong>
        <input type="text" name="j_username" size="25">
    <p>

    <p>
        <strong>Password: </strong>
        <input type="password" size="15" name="j_password">
    <p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

LoginError.jsp contains

```
<h2>Invalid user name or password.</h2>
```

The Database is:

```
CREATE TABLE `cb_groups` (
  `groupname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`)
);

INSERT INTO `cb_groups` VALUES ('admin','admin',1),('user','user',2);

CREATE TABLE `cb_users` (
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
);

INSERT INTO `cb_users` VALUES ('admin','21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3'),('user','21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3');
```

I used the snippet to generate the hash inserted into the database.

```
System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest("admin".getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

Unfortunately access to /contextRoot/protected/* always returns the login page all attempt to athenticate either username/password as user/admin or admin/admin always return the "Invalid user name or password" from loginError.jsp with any server log. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For starters: https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE

Answer (score 0):

Your rolesQuery value should look like this:

```
select groupname, 'Roles' from cb_groups where username = ?
```

You find on https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Authentication+Modules how a database auth module option should be designed.